# unit test for relationship in laravel Model

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, constraints

I am new for laravel model unit testing.so please look and suggest me what i am doing wrong.my code is given below.I have 2 models User and UserState.

**Model User**

```
public function state()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('UserState');
    }
```

**Model UserState**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

now i am writing unit test for UserState. which is given below :

**UnitTest UserStateModelTest**

```
public function testUserRelationIsTrue(){
    $user = new User();
    $user->username = 'testusername';
    $user->save();
    $this->assertEquals($user->user_id, $user->state->id);
}
```

during test run by phpunit it generate error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Comment: Do you have migrations scripts for those tables to show us?

Comment: First off, you are testing Eloquent, which you don't need. Secondly, you never associate `state` to the `users`, so it can't pass. And lastly, `$state->user_id == $user->id` given the relation, you've setup. EDIT: one more thing - consider transactions or db recreation for your tests, or use in-memory, instead of hitting the real db.

Comment: @Unnawut       yes i have. so may i paste those file code here

Comment: True to @JarekTkaczyk words, you are testing Eloquent, which is bad practice. Remember as Jeffrey Way says, there's no need for you to start testing whether Eloquent can save models, Tylor has already tested it.

What you need to do is instead mock the User Model with Mockery and assert that it receives the method "save()" once.

[Mocking - Laravel Docs] (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mocking)

[Getting Started with Mockery](http://culttt.com/2013/07/22/getting-started-with-mockery/)

Those will get you started.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to test a relationship method, you **can** do it without even saving a model to the database. 
You **still** need to use the RefreshDatabase trait (or the DatabaseMigrations trait) or else the models won't be mapped to any table.

```php
# tests/Unit/ParentTest.php
/**
 * Test Parent has HasMany relationship with Child model
 * @test
 */
public function has_many_children_with_parent_id_fk()
{
    $parent = new Parent;
    $foreign_key = 'parent_id';

    // Get the relationship object, not the data collection
    $relationship = $parent->children();
    $related_model = $relationship->getRelated();

    // Assert this is a HasMany relationship
    $this->assertInstanceOf(HasMany::class, $relationship);
    // Assert the related model is Child
    $this->assertInstanceOf(Child::class, $related_model);
    // Assert the foreign key is the one we specified
    // (This can be useful if you do not use the default one)
    $this->assertEquals($foreign_key, $relationship->getForeignKeyName());
    // Assert the foreign key is a column
    // of the database table mapped by the Child model
    $this->assertTrue(Schema::hasColumns($related_model->getTable(), array($foreign_key)));
}
```

```php
# tests/Unit/ChildTest.php
/**
 * Test Child has belongsTo relationship with Parent model
 * @test
 */
public function belongs_to_parent_with_parent_id_fk()
{
    $child = new Child;
    $foreign_key = 'parent_id';

    // Get the relationship object, not the data collection
    $relationship = $child->parent();
    $related_model = $relationship->getRelated();

    // Assert this is a BelongsTo relationship
    $this->assertInstanceOf(BelongsTo::class, $relationship);
    // Assert the related model is Parent
    $this->assertInstanceOf(Parent::class, $related_model);
    // Assert the foreign key is the one we specified
    // (This can be useful if you do not use the default one)
    $this->assertEquals($foreign_key, $relationship->getForeignKeyName());
    // Assert the foreign key is a column
    // of the database table mapped by the Child model
    $this->assertTrue(Schema::hasColumns($relationship->getParent()->getTable(), array($foreign_key)));
}
```

This is a bit of a handful but you can make a custom assertion to encapsulate all of this in the TestCase all tests files extend. The following methods suited my needs

```php
# tests/TestCase.php
public function assertHasManyUsing($related_model, $relationship, $foreign_key)
{
    $this->assertInstanceOf(HasMany::class, $relationship);
    $this->assertInstanceOf($related_model, $relationship->getRelated());
    $this->assertEquals($foreign_key, $relationship->getForeignKeyName());
    $this->assertTrue(Schema::hasColumns($relationship->getRelated()->getTable(), array($foreign_key)));
}

public function assertBelongsToUsing($related_model, $relationship, $foreign_key)
{
    $this->assertInstanceOf(BelongsTo::class, $relationship);
    $this->assertInstanceOf($related_model, $relationship->getRelated());
    $this->assertEquals($foreign_key, $relationship->getForeignKeyName());
    $this->assertTrue(Schema::hasColumns($relationship->getParent()->getTable(), array($foreign_key)));
}
```

And now, refactoring the tests look like this

```php
# tests/Unit/ParentTest.php
/**
 * Test Parent has HasMany relationship with Child model
 * @test
 */
public function has_many_children_with_parent_id_fk()
{
    $parent = new Parent;

    $this->assertHasManyUsing(Child::class, $parent->children(), 'parent_id');
}
```

```php
# tests/Unit/ChildTest.php
/**
 * Test Child has belongsTo relationship with Parent model
 * @test
 */
public function belongs_to_parent_with_parent_id_fk()
{
    $child = new Child;

    $this->assertBelongsToUsing(Parent::class, $child->parent(), 'parent_id');
}
```

Comment:  RereshDatabase trait deleted my db , thanks for chatGPT suggestion which might have been due to your answer, no thanks dude

Comment: I can hardly be blamed because you configured your testing database to be the same as your production database (did you change the default in-memory sqlite config?) and don't have the habit of creating regular backups...

Comment: Also, I feel the need to point out that ChatGPT came out 3 years after I posted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Argument #1 of PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertInstanceOf() must be a
> class or interface name
>
> tests\TestCase.php:14

```
>      10▕     use CreatesApplication;
>      11▕
>      12▕     public function assertHasManyUsing($related_model, $relationship, $foreign_key)
>      13▕ {  
>   ➜ 14▕     $this->assertInstanceOf(HasMany::class, $relationship);     
>      15▕     $this->assertInstanceOf($related_model, $relationship->getRelated());
>      16▕     $this->assertEquals($foreign_key, $relationship->getForeignKeyName());
>      17▕     $this->assertTrue(Schema::hasColumns($relationship->getRelated()->getTable(),
> array($foreign_key)));
>      18▕ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am testing model relationships in this way

```
$this->assertTrue($comment->user()->exists());
```